# ACT Question - r^x is always decreasing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the problem given, but for r: (0,1), isn't it always decreasing?

For all $0 < r < 1$, which of the following describes the function f defined by $f(x)=r^x$.

A) $f(x)$ is constant for all $x$

B) $f$ is decreasing for all $0 \le x < 1$ and increasing for all $x > 1$

C) $f$ is increasing for all $0 \le x < 1$ and decreasing for all $x > 1$

D) $f$ is decreasing for $x < 0$ and decreasing for $x > 0$

D) $f$ is decreasing for $x < 0$ and increasing for $x > 0$

However, exponential functions with the base : $0 <  b < 1$ are always decreasing.

Comment: Write down the questions, never link to a photo of them. Show us that you at least tried to solve it yourself. This behavior isn't accepted on here. Look up the community guidelines on how to write better questions before posting for the fist time. Doing as you've done won't let you any answers by other MSE users

Comment: Alright, I will fix that. When I had posted, I assumed it would show the screenshot embedded in the post.

Comment: Yes, it's showing, but you would have a major chance of someone answering to your post if it's well written and you show us that you thought about it! I don't want to be rude, just wanted to clarify

Comment: You have a transcription error.  As it is written, none of the above are true.

Comment: @DougM None of them are true regardless... none of them say "f is always decreasing"

Comment: What have you tried. Questions that seem basic where the person posting hardly seemed to put in the work don't play well here.

Comment: @Mike What?? I said that exponential functions with a proper fractional base decrease for all values of x, meaning I thought about it. Don't mean to sound rude, but tell me an option on there that says it decreases for all x. Only D, as stated below, is true, but choice D doesn't include x=0, which is thus a mathematically incorrect conclusion.

Comment: @HarrisB my apologies I probably commented before seeing your edit. IF the question is multiple choice and none of the answers are correct, then the person writing the test made an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly a function defined as $$y=a^x$$ with $0<a<1$ is always decreasing, it's simply an exponential. None of the answers proposed are true! Just to be clear, let's choose a simple example, let's say $y=({1\over 2})^x$ has graph [image: exponential]

The only possibility is that the "true" answer is $D$ because the function going to more negative values of $x$ is increasing. But this is not at all mathematically correct